# Creating an event when a form is closed

Tags: c#, forms, exit

I want to create a method that when the x button that closes the application is pressed (it is in the upper right hand corner) I save all the text into a file. From my limited c# experience when I click on a button or text box a method is created, however when I click on the x it takes me to the method for when the windows form is loaded.  When I did a Google search the results pointed me to if I wanted to close the application not make an event happen when the form is closed.  How do I get create an event when the form is closed?

Comment: Use the FormClosed event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the form selected in the Designer in Visual Studio, you can select the FormClosed event from the Properties window and it will automatically generate an event method for when the form is closed, which you can then add your relevant code to.

Answer (score 2):

You can register to [`Form.FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
Form form1 = new Form();
form1.FormClosing += (o, e) => 
{
    // Do stuff you want
}
```

Comment: Just asking if you do not mind for knowledge. What is the difference between your code and mine? I know that both will do the same thing.

Comment: Mine uses a `Lambda Expression` to register to the event, and you're using a `Named Method`

Comment: You are using the obsolete method, lol

Comment: Sometimes this happens. This is really funny. ;)

Comment: Hey, Form.Closing and this.FormClosing sound pretty similar xD

Comment: Still not fixed completely :P, "You can register to Form.Closing event:"

Answer (score 1):

Add this code on FormLoad:

```
this.FormClosing += MainPage_FormClosing; // occurs before closing of the form
this.FormClosed += MainPage_FormClosed; // occurs after the closing of the form


private void MainPage_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here to do something before closing the form
}

private void MainPage_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here to do something after the form is closed
}
```

I think this is the answer to your question.

Comment: "The Closing event is obsolete in the .NET Framework version 2.0; use the FormClosing event instead." I think you misread it. I am using FormClosing not Form.Closing :P

Comment: Dude I am using FormClosing not Form.Closing. Please read the code again.

Comment: Yuval, delete your comments as they are not relevant and misleading. You misread his code, he is not using Form.Closing.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Dude please read my code again. I am NOT USING THE OBSOLETE METHOD :P

Comment: It's this.FormClosing, not this.Closing.